Define primary key when converting shapefile
I am currently trying to convert a shapefile into a .sql file with the shp2sql command, but when it generates the .sql file, it generates a gid column twice, one that's inherent to the shapefile I am using and another the command generates when I run it. Is there a way to define the gid column as the primary key when running the command so that it doesn't create another gid column?

Maybe you can edit the created SQL file and add a primary key constraint to that column.

@FardinEsmaeili Yes I can do that, the problem is that I am working with automating a process, so I need to do it through a command line or some other way.

shp2pgsql has a -m option for mapping column names that can be used to avoid an error due to the duplicated gid column.
  -m <filename>  Specify a file containing a set of mappings of (long) column
     names to 10 character DBF column names. The content of the file is one or
     more lines of two names separated by white space and no trailing or
     leading space. For example:
         COLUMNNAME DBFFIELD1
         AVERYLONGCOLUMNNAME DBFFIELD2

Create a file with the contents "__gid gid" (without the quotes) and then supply that into -m.  The command doesn't mind if a column in the map file doesn't exist so it's safe to re-use the mapping files for all shapefiles that might or might not have a gid columns.
For example
$ echo __gid gid > /tmp/map
$ shp2pgsql -m /tmp/map my_shapefile.shp schema.table

You can append a query to drop the __gid column at the end of the generated SQL if you don't want the duplicated column at all.
